# Nested generic type parameters - how to handle it?

Tags: c#, generics

I created some methods that use nested type parameters generic types in the parameter declaration:

```
public void Foo(IList<Pair<double, IList<double>>> myParameter)
{ // code goes here 
}
```

What I wanted to achieve was to force this method to accept 4 types of variables:

- `List<Pair<double, List<double>>> myVar`
- `List<Pair<double, double[]>> myVar`
- `Pair<double, List<double>>[] myVar`
- `Pair<double, double[]>[] myVar`

But it seems that second, nested interface cannot be converted on-the-fly by C#. While trying to pass some of variables listed above to my method, I get error:

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<...> to Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IList<...>

Do I really need to create two aliases for this method to handle this problem? Or maybe there is some kind of trick that I could use to overcome this problem?

Comment: You want a method that can accept both a `something` *and* a `List<something>`? That seems a little odd - what's the use case?

Comment: @AakashM: No, look at the `[]`. Both instantiate `IList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code leads to a variance problem.

The inner `IList<double>` would allow you to assign `List<double>` even if you originally passed a `double[]`, which would break type safety.

(This occurs fore the same reason as `List<Orange>` may not be treated as a `List<Fruit>`: You could push apples into it.)

In order to achieve correct variance behaviour, you'll have to ensure immutability as through the use of `IEnumerable<T>`s instead of `IList<T>`s (just works under .NET 4.0).

The previous versions of C# aren't able to handle variance at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can use generic constraints in C# 2.0+

```
void Foo<TList>(IList<Pair<double, TList>> myParameter)
   where TList : IList<double>
```

C# has trouble with the type inference on this one though, so you will need to specify during calling.

Comment: Thanks, it is some kind of solution but in the end it causes more trouble, than it is worth. Thanks anyway, for this try

Comment: +1, but the `TList1` parameter is unnecessary here, which would simplify the signature and allow type inference to succeed in more cases.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you are passing, the issue here is more than likely due to the fact that you don't have [variance on generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359.aspx).

Fortunately, in C# 4.0, this exists, and I'd be willing to guess that you could use `IEnumerable<double>` as the inner type parameter and it would work (unless you have a need to mutate the list as opposed to just iterating it.

If you are not able to use C# 4.0, then you are going to have to change the type parameter of your `List<T>` variable to the specific type requested.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot use C# 4.0 so probably I will have to create some aliases :/